# Get repeated elements from list

Tags: java

I need to get elements from database which repeat more than 3 times. Here is my code how I do this:

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getPrice(List<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int val;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        val = list.get(i);
        if (!map.containsKey(val)) {
            map.put(val, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(val, map.get(val) + 1);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 3) {
result.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is it good and effective way?

Comment: If it's an SQL database, wouldn't it be easier to `SELECT ... GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`?

Comment: If someone asked me "what could `getPrice` method possibly do?", I would have never guessed that it finds elements that are repeated three or more times in a list of integers.

Comment: it will be SQLite database in android project. About integer, of course the price will not be integer type, it just for test.

Comment: NPE, your advice works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the liste in a database, I will advice you to use SQL. But if you want to do that in java, you could do that:

```
public static List<Integer> getPrice(List<Integer> list) {
    SetUniqueList<Integer> result = new SetUniqueList<Integer>();
    for (Integer number : list) {
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(list, number); 
        if (occurrences > 3) {
            result.add(number);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or without  org.apache.commons.collections.list:

```
public static List<Integer> getPrice(List<Integer> list) {
    Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Integer number : list) {
        if (Collections.frequency(list, number) > 3) {
            aSet.add(number);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    result.addAll(aSet);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "But if you really want to do that in java" not I just did not know how to do it in database SQLite. I am searching for more efficient way how to do it.

Comment: If you want to do that with SQL you have a good solution in the comments of your question

Answer (score 0):

There can be more efficient solutions but if you think about the runtime it should be alright. In fact you have 2 for-loops where the one with the bigger count dominates which leads to O(n) where n is the number of the elements of the larger Array.
This a good runtime.